# Склеивание numpy массивов поэлементно

Tags: python, numpy

Нужно склеить массивы (первый элемент первого с первым, второй элемент со вторым и т.д., чтобы в итоге получилось что-то вроде скалярного произведения `array([0.5, 0], [0.5, 1])`
Придуманный мной вариант почему-то дублирует элементы: `[[0.5, 0], [0.5, 1], [0.5, 0], [0.5, 1]]` В идеале хотелось бы обойтись без циклов, но не знаю как реализовать

```
  X_train =  np.array([[1, 1], [2, 2]])
  y_train =  np.array([0, 1])
  X_test =  np.array([[1.5, 1.5]])

a = np.sum((X_test - X_train)**2, axis=1)
print([[i, j] for i in a for j in y_train])
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Примените функцию `np.column_stack()` или `np.stack()`:

```
np.column_stack((a, y_train))         # или np.stack((a, y_train), axis=1)
```

Результат:

> ```
> array([[0.5, 0. ],
>        [0.5, 1. ]])
> ```

---

*Примечание:*

Вами предложенный результат `array([0.5, 0], [0.5, 1])` не возможен, в `numpy` *не существует массив с элементами типа* **списков**.

Вы, вероятно, пропустили внешние квадратные (или обычные) скобки, нужные для получения 2-мерного массива **чисел**:

- `np.array([0.5, 0], [0.5, 1])` выдает ошибку (второй параметр должен быть тип элементов), но
- `np.array(([0.5, 0], [0.5, 1]))` создает правильный двухмерный массив:

  > ```
  > array([[0.5, 0. ],
  >        [0.5, 1. ]])
  > ```